# How to use argsparse to access part of a config file in python?

Tags: python, attributes, arguments

I have this config.py file:

```
# config.py 

maria = dict(
    corners = [1,2,3,4],
    area = 2100
)

john = dict(
        corners = [5,6,7,8],
        area = 2400 
    )
```

and want to use parameters from it by running my main program using `argsparse`. somewhat like this:

```
# main.py

import config
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("user", help="maria or john")
args = parser.parse_args()
print(args.user)
print(config.args.user['corners'])
```

when I run:

```
pyhton3 main.py maria
```

I get syntax error on the 2nd print, where I would like to get `[1,2,3,4]`.
How can I use the argument from `argparse` as an attribute to access the appropriate data in the config file?

Comment: Why do you have the `config` prefix  on `config.args.user['corners']` instead of just `args.user['corners']`?

Comment: I have the config prefix because I want to read from the config.py  file. If I print(config.maria['corners'] I will get the required result. What I need now is to replace that maria by an argument aquired from argsparse.

Comment: I would encourage you to *not* use an arbitrary Python module as configuration. Your example could be handled with a JSON file that can be parsed by the `json` module without executing arbitrary code.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @chepner I will look into that. I believe YAML is a good option too, but for a POC I tried a .py file first.

Comment: The `json` module is, at least, in the standard library, while a YAML parser would require a 3rd party module. A small barrier, but something to consider.

Comment: If you want the best of both worlds, consider a restricted language like [Dhall](http://dhall-lang.org) to *generate* the JSON or YAML config. Someday, there may even be Python bindings for Dhall that would allow you to process a Dhall file directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using executable Python code for configuration. Use something like JSON:

`config.json` would look like

```
{
    "maria": {
        "corners": [1,2,3,4],
        "area": 2100
    },
    "john": {
        "corners": [5,6,7,8],
        "area": 2400
    }
}
```

And your script would use

```
# main.py

import json
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("user", help="maria or john")
args = parser.parse_args()
with open("config.json") as f:
    config = json.load(f)

print(args.user)
print(config[args.user]['corners'])
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC:
You can use the `getattr` built in function in python.

**The `getattr(object, name[, default])`:**

> Return the value of the named attribute of object. name must be a
>   string. If the string is the name of one of the object’s attributes,
>   the result is the value of that attribute. For example, getattr(x,
>   'foobar') is equivalent to x.foobar. If the named attribute does not >exist, default is returned if provided, otherwise AttributeError is raised.

Replace:

```
print (config.args.user['corners'])
```

**With:**

```
print(getattr(config, args.user)["corners"])
```

Comment: Thanks Shubham, but I get this : AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'user'

Comment: If there is no named attribute corresponding to `args.user` in. `config` then you are going to get `AttributeError`

Answer (score 0):

One way to go around this is to wrap your parameters in one general dict:

```py
# config.py

params = {'maria': {'corners': [1,2,3,4], 'area': 2100},
          'john':  {'corners': [5,6,7,8], 'area': 2400}}
```

And then you can simply do in `main.py`:

```py
print(config.params[args.user]['corners'])
```